# Wrong scroll position when deeplinking with hash to page section

Tags: hash, routes, deep-linking, sveltekit, scroll-position

I'm running a SvelteKit project. A link on my homepage references a page section by **hash** / **id** on an other page. When I click the link (CSR) the specific page is opened at the wrong scroll position. When I refresh the page or copy / past the url (SSR) the page position scrolls to the referenced page section.

Homepage:
`<a href="/detailpage#section-name">`

Detailpage:
`<section id="section-name">`

What can be the reason for the wrong scroll position with client side rendering in SvelteKit?